# PostgreSQL backup with smallest output files

Tags: postgresql-8.1

We have a Postgresql database that is over 732 GB when backed as a file system backup.  When we do a pg_dump we can get it down to 585 GB.  If I combined the pg_dump with the PITR method will this give me the best backup with smallest backup data file size?  My plan was to run the pg_start_backup, then the pg_dump, then the pg_stop_backup.  I know the documentation states to run a file system backup but I want a smaller backup data set.  I would then copy off WAL files and then backup them up at night.

Answer (score 0):

To truly get the smallest file, you'll have to try compressing your `pg_dump -Fc` dump file with one of many compression tools and settings. Using `gzip` or `xz` with maximum possible compression would be a start. This will of course require an excellent CPU and lots of CPU time.